# wcf webservice using mtom to stream binary data gets error "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response ***"

Tags: wcf, web-services, serialization, mtom

I have to develop a web service that is able to send emails with attachment and a client using wcf and mtom for serialization. I use the following tools for my work:

Windows 7 Professional x64
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
Microsoft Development Server/ IIS Express 8.0
User: administrator

Each time i try to use the webservice in my client with self-defined classes from a message contract i receive the error "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to `http://localhost:2364/Service1.svc`. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Now, I just try to set up a simple test service and a simple test client. I tried the following things and always get the same error, while using methods from the webservice that just uses simple strings in request and response works quite well without any errors.

1. Same error on integrated Microsoft Development Server from Visual Studio 2012 and IIS Express 8.0
2. Same error using basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding in configuration for client and service
3. Tried to generate logging files on both servers. The IIS Express Server generates some logs in an other folder than configured but not with the settings from my configuration file. The Microsoft Development Server generates nothing.
4. I used svctraceviewer.exe to watch the few generated logging files and just saw some warnings with the opcode MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS. I cannot understand this information.
5. I tried to enable read/write-permission for localService and networkService to the specified folders with no result.
6. I tried to use RawCap to sniff the localhost and watch the result with wireshark but the output file has 0 bytes (This must be another problem).

Please let me know if you need further information.

Thank you!

Below is my code and configuration for service and client (just for testing):

**Service: IService1.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WcfTestService
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    /*
    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);*/

    // TODO: Hier Dienstvorgänge hinzufügen

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse TestCase(ServiceRequest testRequest);
}

/*
// Verwenden Sie einen Datenvertrag, wie im folgenden Beispiel dargestellt, um Dienstvorgängen zusammengesetzte Typen hinzuzufügen.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}*/

[MessageContract]
public class ServiceRequest
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Contents { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Contents { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Service: web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"  switchValue="Ausführlich,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Ausführlich,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="d:\log\web_messages.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
  <add initializeData="d:\log\web_tracelog.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<!--httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="7200"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
    messageFlowTracing="true" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpMtomBinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
      openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
      transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000" maxStringContentLength="1000" maxArrayLength="1000"
        maxBytesPerRead="1000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpMtomBinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" messageEncoding="Mtom"
useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="1000" maxArrayLength="1000"
        maxBytesPerRead="100000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000" />
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="10:10:00" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <remove scheme="http" />
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpMtomBinding" />
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpsBinding" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
    Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Client: app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2364/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="Ares\Admin" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Client: Form1.cs**

```
     ...

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ServiceReference1.IService1 testService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        ServiceReference1.ServiceRequest testInput = new ServiceReference1.ServiceRequest();
        ServiceReference1.ServiceResponse testOutput = new ServiceReference1.ServiceResponse();

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream inoutStream = new MemoryStream();

        testInput.Type = "TestType";
        String test = "TestContent";
        testInput.Contents = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(testInput.Contents, test);
        //testInput.Contents.Position = 0;

        testService.TestCase(testInput);


        MessageBox.Show("Done!");

    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any service configuration data in web.config (endpoint etc.)

```
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="..." name="[Namespace].Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="..." bindingConfiguration="..." contract="[Namespace].IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5000/Service1"/>
...
```

You can configure endpoints at runtime (basically in self-hosted services) but for simple scenarios and IIS infrastructure...?

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx